# DependencyProperty Memory leak

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

I am using PerfView in order to discover memory leaks.

After comparing between two snapshot I noticed that under the tab RefTree -> static vars in PerView.
`MyPageDependencyProperty` of mine takes 78.9% of the Inc%.

The `MyPageDependencyProperty` should not be there because I closed the the xaml window it is belong to.

I don't use `AddValueChanged` which can cause memory leak.

The `DependencyProperty` reveals  `ObservableCollection<object>`.

Does anyone know can I solve this issue?

thanks

Comment: How do you define the property?

Comment: I define it by public static readonly DependencyProperty
and it points to Public ObservableCollectio<object>

Comment: There you go that is your memory leak. You created a static ObservableCollection. Let me post you an answer that will solve your concerns.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of defining your property like this which creates a static ObservableCollection.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SomePropertyProperty  = DependencyProperty.Register(typeof(..), typeof(..),....,.... , new ObservableCollection<...>());
```

You should do this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SomePropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(typeof(..), typeof(..),...., null);

public MyControl()
{
   this.SomeProperty = new ObservableCollection<...>();
}
```

And your issue will disappear magically. :)

Comment: I have a question. Static members are associated with their types. so when the application runs, and an object is instantiated of a class, a type instance (i.e., Foo+<>c) is created as well in the memory along with its static members, right? so when a normal instance of the class is not in use, why GC is not able to remove it from the memory? I feel there is something missing I cannot grasp the whole idea.

Answer (score -3):

This may be because of CLR has the links to the object somewhere and it doesn't `Dispose`. Try to [force Garbage collector to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257372/how-to-force-garbage-collector-to-run) and track what will happen.

Comment: I did 
GC.Collect(MaxGeneration,Forced)
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers)

Still There

Comment: Whatever, memory leaks are always caused by hanging references