# Memory Leak in c# or something of that matter

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, memory-leaks

First I'm sorry that I'm asking this totally ambiguous question. I have encountered a very confusing problem that I don't know how to solve.

It is not even possible to write some sample code here because it is related to my application as a whole. I'll try to explain this though.

I have two `Canvas` objects:

- Canvas A
- Canvas B

that I'm using in my application to draw `Line` objects on them. I also have two `Button` objects that I use to switch between `Canvas A` and `Canvas B`.

Now When I switch to `Canvas A` I start drawing on `Canvas A` and I clear all of the children in `Canvas B` and when I switch to `Canvas B` I start drawing on `Canvas B` and I clear the children of `Canvas A`.

*After some time going back and forth* between these two canvases, my program becomes **very slow**. I tried **Ant Profiler** and took memory snapshots. Once when I start the program and once when I feel that it has become slow.

The difference in size is around 135 KB. Is this a memory leak? 135 KB doesn't seem to be that much? What else can cause the problem?

Do the `Line` objects that I draw each time when I switch reside and aggregate in the memory despite the fact that I clear the children of the canvas? Since the number of the `Line` objects are high they may cause a problem if they reside and aggregate each time. How can I make sure?

Any suggestions are truly appreciated.

**Update:**

when I switch to CanvasB this is the code I use to clean the CanvasA:

```
CanvasA.Children.Clear();
```

I'm using `DrawingVisual` to draw the lines.

Comment: I'd suspect it has something to do with how you're clearing the canvas'. You should add the relevant code.

Comment: How do you Draw, how do you Clear?

Comment: @Sayse @ Henk I updated the question.

Comment: If you are using `DrawingVisual` instead of `Canvas.Children.Add(line)`, I'm not sure, but shouldn't you deal with `DrawingContext` rather than clear `Canvas`?

Comment: I suggest you see if forcing the garbage collector  to run fixes the problem or maybe makes it not as bad.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257372/how-to-force-garbage-collector-to-run and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @philologon I tried it too. It doesn't happen to solve the problem either. What has confused me is that the difference between the two memory snapshots is very small. So it is not memory leak is it?

Comment: @Bolu I'm using `using` when drawing on the `DrawingVisual` so I guess it is disposed after that right?

Comment: Ok guys after so much trouble I think I found the culprit. It was the `Event Listeners`. Thank you all.