# Can I call specific generation GC

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I'm interested if we can specifically call full GC or level 1 GC ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I'm just curious of possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the generation when calling `Collect` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/y46kxc5e(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
GC.Collect(1);
```

As Essigwurst wrote - remember about calling `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` afterwards.
Bare in mind that explicitly collecting is not reccomended because of permormance issues. You can get more information in these threads:

- [How to force garbage collector to run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257372/how-to-force-garbage-collector-to-run)
- [Best Practice for Forcing Garbage Collection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233596/best-practice-for-forcing-garbage-collection-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I should be smarter and check it myself ) Thanks, that is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `GC.Collect()` and then `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()`; else i don't think it's possible..

Comment: Can You please explain why should I call WaitForPendingFinalizers() ?