# UWP application is getting slow after usage of some time?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, uwp

I have developed one **UWP** application.In that nearly **20 windows** are there.

Every window contains lot of `Xaml` controls. For some time it's working fine.

**But after usage of some time application is getting very slow.**

After doing some R&D I came to know that it's called **Memory Leakage**.

As per my knowledge in **.Net Garbage Collector** has to take care of this if I am not wrong.It seems like In **UWP** Application it is not happening. So I thought I should use `GC.Collect()` in `Page Unload Event`.

Is that correct approach or anything else I need to do to release memory which are used by the window controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance optimization is a vast subject and may not be possible to answer on an open ended question (without knowledge of your environment and architecture etc).

However you can use the Visual Studio profiler to measure and track performance and to find out the area where you need to take action, these can be;

- Data binding
- UI Virtualization
- Image rendering
- Visual Tree Size

Further reading these urls may also help you.

[ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-xaml-loading) and this [blog](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/10/07/optimizing-your-xaml-app-for-performance-10-by-10/#0L2PVQ1ctJYWbLfW.97)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Could  you please clarify me once that is it cause any issue if I use GC.Collect() method in Unload event. Does GC.Collect() releases the memory which are used by the current page.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257372/how-to-force-garbage-collector-to-run and https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/uwp-resources-unloadunusedassets-behaves-differently-against-weakreference.416888/ and https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/issues/777 and https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/RefCycles.htm

Answer (score 1):

The GC takes care of orphaned objects or objects that are no longer referenced by any other classes. when the GC finds objects like these it removes them from memory. memory leaks happen when an object is referenced by another class even after it is done with it. this means you need to look at your code and find where this is happening. you need to help GC in doing its job by making sure you no longer reference objects you don't need.
I also wouldn't recommend using `GC.Collect` in page unload event since GC has to freeze threads in order to collect. this might impact performance.