# Will nulling an object in session destroy it right away

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session, garbage-collection

I have a large object I would like to store in `session`, maybe a minute to use, and than remove it from memory.  How long does an object stay in `Gen0`, `Gen1` before it stays in Gen2 until GC?  If I `NULL` it after a minute will the memory be cleared right away or at least in Gen0 or Gen1?  I would like to free up that memory as fast as possible so it doesnt go to Gen2.

```
Session["Object"] = null;
```

Comment: [Theory] Create an object with a destructor `~`, place a breakpoint in the destructor, then run under your debugger. Should tell you when its getting destroyed.

Comment: Your session object will only be garbage collected when the session times out.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not deterministic, since it is optimized.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals

But here is how you can force it:

[How to force garbage collector to run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257372/how-to-force-garbage-collector-to-run)

`System.GC.Collect();`

Comment: `System.GC.Collect();` does not mean it will run immediately.

Comment: @SᴇM could you elaborate, I only found data it will not necessarily clean up everything.

Comment: `Collect()` will message CLR to start collection, but that does not mean it will start immediately after that line.

Comment: I'm not sure that setting null to the session object and force GC.Collect will release it since it may still be referenced elsewhere.

Comment: When you say start collection, does it mean Gen0 or Gen2? Does it mean only the session object or all objects?

Comment: @Mikr Flynn, calling GC.Collect without parameters will clean all generations. But it have other overloads if you want to clean an específic generation: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=net-5.0